# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x^2 - 9}$ with L'Hopital's rule gives me a different answer than what I expect

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x^2 - 9}$$
Since $$\lim_{x \to 3} \log(1+x) - \log(4)=0$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 3} x^2 - 9 = 0$$
we should be able to use L'Hopital's rule to see that
$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x^2 - 9} = \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{1/(1+x)}{2x} = \frac{0.25}{6} = 0.042$$
But when I graph the equation I see that the limit is $0.018$.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Be careful that you're using logarithm to the right base.  Maybe the plot assumes base $10$?  I point this out because $\ln 10 \approx 2.3$ and $0.042/2.3 \approx 0.018$.

Comment: Yea thats exactly it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed in the comments there is an issue with the base for logarithm and your evaluation is right, as an alternative without l'Hospital we can refer to the definition of derivative by $f(x)=\log(1+x)$

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x^2 - 9}=\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{1}{x+3}\cdot \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x-3}=\frac16 \cdot f'(3)$$

or also by standard limits with $h=x-3 \to 0$

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\log(1+x) - \log(4)}{x^2 - 9}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(4+h) - \log(4)}{h(h+6)}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{4(h+6)}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac h4\right)}{\frac h4} = \frac1{24}$$